# define R function receiving a function argument as a function call without evaluating it

Tags: r

I'm looking to define a function 'f' that receives a function as an argument in the following way:

```
f <- function(c,z(...))
{
  print(c) 
  z(...)
}
```

such that if I define:

```
f1 <- function(a) 
{
  print(a)
}
f2 <- function(a,b) 
{
  print(a) 
  print(b)
}
```

I can call 'f' in the following way:

```
f(1,f1(2))
1
2

f(1,f2(2,3))
1
2
3
```

I'm aware that I'm able to define 'f' this way:

```
f <- function(c,z,...)
{
  print(c)
  z(...)
}
```

and call 'f':

```
f(1,f1,2)
f(1,f2,1,2)
```

but this is less readable as one cannot tell by looking on the function call that f1/2 is a function argument and the following arguments are used by that particular function.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do:

```
f = function(x,y){
    print(x)
    y
}

f1 = function(x,y){
    print(x)
    print(y)
}
```

Note that the first function (`f`) takes a second parameter and it is not evaluated.

In this case you can call the functions like you wanted:

```
> f(1,f1(2,3))
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
```

Or

```
> f(4,f1)(5,6)
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
```

In this last case, `f(4,f1)` returns a function that is later evaluated with (5,6).

Comment: thanks, this address my requirement. according to the first call: f(1,f1(2,3)) - is that general that inner function argument is eventuated only when used inside the function and not in the beginning of the function? about the second call f(4,f1)(5,6) - it does not work when inside apply function; error message:  "Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : attempt to apply non-function" is there a fix here?

Answer (score 0):

```
f <- function(c,d)
{ 
  print(c) 
  d
}

f1 <- function(a)
{
  print(a)
}
f2 <- function(a,b) 
{
  print(a) 
  print(b)
}
```

Test :

```
> f(1,f2(2,3))
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3

> f(1,f1(2))
[1] 1
[1] 2
```